# why is this synchronized method not working as expected?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a class called MyRunnable:

```
public class MyRunnable extends Main implements Runnable  {
  String name; // name of thread
  Thread t;

  MyRunnable (String threadname) {
      name = threadname;
      t = new Thread(this, name);
      t.start();
  }

  public void run() {
      try {
          for (int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
              extend(1);
          }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          System.out.println("Thread interrupted.");
      }
      System.out.println("Thread " +  name + " exiting.");
  }

}
```

and a class called Main:

```
public class Main {
  private static List<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<>();

  public synchronized void extend (int i) throws InterruptedException {
      numbers.add(i);
  }
  public synchronized static int getSize() {
      return numbers.size();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyRunnable t0=new MyRunnable("0");
      MyRunnable t1=new MyRunnable("1");
      MyRunnable t2=new MyRunnable("2");

      try {
          t0.t.join();
          t1.t.join();
          t2.t.join();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {

      }
      System.out.println(getSize());
  }
}
```

Now I would be expecting to get 300000 as output but instead I get a random number (approx. between 250000 and 290000) even though I did use synchronized methods. I did read the oracle's documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html but I can't seem to figure out why this is not working as expected. Could someone explain me why ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're creating three `MyRunnable` instances. Each is synchronizing on itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods are synchronized to the object calling them. You need to create an object shared between each of the objects and have them synchronize on that object.

```
private static List<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<>();
public synchronized void extend (int i) throws InterruptedException {
    synchronize(numbers) {
        numbers.add(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`synchronized` here locks on the object against which the method `extend` is invoked (since it is an instance method). Therefore, you're synchronizing on three different objects.

If you synchronize on the shared `static` list (for example), you would get the expected result.